# Is it possible to have an animated SVG as a vector layer feature?

Tags: openlayers, svg

Is it possible to have an animated svg as a vector layer feature?  I'm using D3 to make the animation. Here's my animated svg: https://jsfiddle.net/eflowbeach/opfkh0n9/1/

I thought I was onto something when I got this to work:

```
// Turn the svg into an xml string for use in OpenLayers
var svgstring = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(d3.select(svg.node()).node());
```

where svg is the animated version, but it only captures a snapshot of the animation.

I get this into OpenLayers like this:

```
 new ol.style.Style({
                image: new ol.style.Icon({
                    src: 'data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(svgstring)
                })
            });
```

After I got this to work, it makes sense why it is not animated; the string will only capture the current state of the svg. So, is there another way to do this or do I have to look into putting this on a canvas?

Comment: try this animated svg [strategies] code http://www.acuriousanimal.com/AnimatedCluster/

Comment: Do you want this svg to be of constant size or zoomable?

Comment: @TomazicM I would like it to scale as the user zooms in.

Comment: Then it's going to be a bit more complicated, I'll have solution this evening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Animated svg with static (non zoomable) size can be put on map via `ol.Overlay` layer. Overlay can be use to display any html element on the map. In this case svg is embedded in `div` element.

Basis for code below was taken from OpenLayers [Overlay example](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/overlay.html):

```
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
<div style="display: none;">
  <a class="overlay" id="vienna" target="_blank" href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vienna">Vienna</a>
  <div id="svgContainer" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;">
     <svg viewBox="0 0 200 200" style="width: 100%; height: auto"></svg>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
  var svgLonLat = [16.3725, 48.208889];
  var svgPosition = ol.proj.fromLonLat(svgLonLat);
  var svgContainer = document.getElementById('svgContainer');

  var layer = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.OSM()
  });

  var scaleLineControl = new ol.control.ScaleLine();

  var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [layer],
    target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View({
      center: svgPosition,
      zoom: 8
    }),
    controls: ol.control.defaults().extend([scaleLineControl])
  });

  var svgLayer = new ol.Overlay({
    position: svgPosition,
    positioning: 'center-center',
    element: document.getElementById('svgContainer'),
    stopEvent: false
  });
  map.addOverlay(svgLayer);

  var vienna = new ol.Overlay({
    position: svgPosition,
    element: document.getElementById('vienna')
  });
  map.addOverlay(vienna);

  function lineAnimate(selection) {
    selection
      .attr('x1', 100)
      .attr('y1', 100)
      .attr('x2', 100) //function(d) {return d;})
      .attr('y2', 100) //function(d) {return d;})
      .attr('stroke', '#000000')
      .attr('stroke-width', 5)
      .style('opacity', 0.7)
      .transition()
      .ease(d3.easeLinear)
      .duration(200)
      .attr('x2', 200)
      .transition()
      .duration(1000)
      .style('opacity', 0)
      .on('end', function() {
          d3.select(this).call(lineAnimate);
      });
  }

  d3.select('svg')
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .selectAll('line')
    .data([0])
    .enter()
    .append('line')
    .call(lineAnimate);      
</script>
```

To make svg resize when zooming, it has to be resized at the end of zoom event. Size of svg in meters is also defined (`lenM`) and minimal size in pixels for svg to be displayed on map (`minLenPixels`):

```
var minLenPixels = 20;
var lenM = 50000;
svgContainer.style.display = 'none';

map.on('moveend', function() {
  var svgPixelPos = map.getPixelFromCoordinate(svgPosition);
  var svgPixelPos2 = map.getPixelFromCoordinate([svgPosition[0] + lenM, svgPosition[1]]);
  var lenPixels = svgPixelPos2[0] - svgPixelPos[0];

  var view = map.getView();
  var projection = view.getProjection();
  var resolutionAtEquator = view.getResolution();
  var center = view.getCenter();
  var pointResolution = ol.proj.getPointResolution(projection, resolutionAtEquator, center);
  var resolutionFactor = resolutionAtEquator/pointResolution;

  lenPixels = (lenPixels / projection.getMetersPerUnit()) * resolutionFactor;
  var svgWidth = lenPixels * 2;

  if (lenPixels < minLenPixels)
    svgContainer.style.display = 'none';
  else {
    svgContainer.style.width = svgWidth + "px";
    svgContainer.style.height = svgWidth + "px";
    svgContainer.style.display = 'block';
  }              
});
```

Comment: Thanks! That's a unique solution - now I have to figure out how to do many of these ;-)